# Looking for the name of a type of jacket

Tags: word-choice

[image: Pintest image of a woman]

I know this likely isn't the proper format for this, but I figured I'd try anyway. I'm looking for the name of an article of clothing most similar to the jacket-esque article worn in the picture.

The closest I've come is a cloth poncho, but that calls up a VERY different image in my head--which I'm betting will be the case for my readers as well. Any suggestions or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a tabard? Are you looking for the garment that covers the chest, the shoulders, or the forearms?

Comment: Chest, shoulders, and somewhat down over the thighs, but leaving arms uncovered (and preferably with a hoodie to cover the head). Tabard seems to come close, but isn't that specifically for knights and squires?

Comment: Yeah. A hooded tabard definitely fits. Thanks @jejorda2

Comment: Not just knights and squires. People who do messy jobs or who want to protect their clothes e.g from splashes often wear tabards. Often these will be  provided by an employer.  [Workwear tabard example](https://www.alexandra.co.uk/hospitality-catering/tabards/long-length-tabard-with-pocket#.W2n5byhKiHs)

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is a (hooded) [tabard](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tabard):

> 1.1historical A coarse sleeveless garment worn as the outer dress of medieval peasants and clerics, or worn as a surcoat over armour.

(That seems to address your concern about who wore them. They are very simple items of clothing so I associate them primarily with poorer/working people.)

The [Wikipedia page on the tabard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabard) mentions another, similar garment:

> A surviving garment similar to the medieval tabard is the monastic [scapular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapular). This is a wide strip of fabric worn front back of the body, with an opening for the head and no sleeves. It may have a hood, and may be worn under or over a belt.

But that has very specific religious connotations.